# ckeditor редактирование html с разметкой textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, ckeditor

Редактирую html-страницу через редактор ckeditor. Всё работает, без проблем. Но! На странице, что редактируется, находится разметка textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="doptextarea" rows="2"></textarea>
```

В ckeditor попадает разметка до textarea, а дальше, весь контент выводится просто на страницу с редактором.
[image: ckeditor и textarea]
Если убрать со страницы textarea - страница адекватно переносится в редактор ckeditor и можно спокойно редактировать контент/разметку.
Вопрос! Как можно отредактировать разметку страницы, на которой находится textarea? Буду очень благодарен Вашим ответам.

Comment: Писать разметку после закрытия блока "<div form-group drop-textarea hidden my-2>" ?

Comment: @Stupid_Pink_Pony Разметка подгружается из стороннего файла php. В том то и фокус, что после встречи <textarea>, прекращается ckeditor-ом чтение разметки из файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему иным образом. Перед загрузкой контента для редактирования заменяю textarea на textarea1. А перед записью сохранений, обратно меняю textarea1 на textarea. Костыль, но работает.
Хотелось бы, конечно, узнать правильное решение, так что буду рад ответам/комментариям.